# $m(A) + m(B) = m(A \cup B) + m(A \cap B)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Does $m(A) + m(B) = m(A \cup B) + m(A \cap B)$ extend to unbounded sets $A,B$. Does unboundedness change anything?

Comment: no i doesn't. {}

Comment: I don't think that changes anything

Comment: no${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The important condition is for $m$ to be defined on those sets, i.e. for those sets to be measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write $$A=(A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B)$$ and $$B=(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$$ and note these decompositions are disjoint. Then $$A\cup B = (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$$ is also a disjoint decomposistion.

So: $$m(A)+m(B) = m(A\setminus B) + m(B\setminus A) + 2m(A\cap B) = m(A\cup B)+m(A\cap B)$$

So the thing you need to know is that if $X,Y$ are measurable, then $X\setminus Y$ and $X\cap Y$ are measurable, too.

Comment: I think there is a way to write $[0,1]=A\cup B$ with the outer measure of $A$ and $B$=1 and $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ Then $m^*(A)+m^*(B)=2\neq 1 = m^*(A\cup B)+m^*(A\cap B)$ But it has been a long time since I've explored measure theory.

Comment: Sorry that I deleted my previous comment, it was a little difficult to express the question properly. I see what you mean, and the info is very helpful - to officially express the question correctly (sorry again for the delay), I'm curious if the equality $m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)=m^{*}(A\cap B)+m^{*}(A\cup B)$ holds (where $m^{*}$ is the Lebesgue outer measure) if only $A$ (or $B$, exclusively) isn't Lebesgue measurable; further, does the equality hold in the event that both $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ are not measurable.

Comment: So, you mean is there is any non-measurable cases where this holds? Sure, when $A$ and $B$ don't interact at all, like $A\subset[0,1]$ and $B\subset [2,3]$, the outer measure sums will be the same.

Comment: Yes. I'm finishing up some work now, and the question is initially posed to prove the equality - which I did using the same technique. Then, the question asks if equality holds when measurability of $A$ is dropped (and to "discuss," not prove); moreover, does the equality hold if (Lebesgue) measurability of $A,B$ is dropped dually (and to discuss this scenario also). I started thinking in terms of unbounded sets of reals which lead me here.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see what you are getting at! Thank you.